# Power output of ignition coil - 2.0

Tags: power, transformer, coil

There was an older question about "Power output of ignition coil".
The system would not let me comment on that question.

So, I'll ask here. In regards to a ignition coil (non specific).

OK,you have 60,000W output in 1ms.

Does the wattage reduce by half each time you increase the time(x) by X?

- 60,000   1ms
- 30,000   2ms
- 15,000   3ms
- 7,500    4ms

What is the formula to convert watts-miliseconds to watts-seconds or watts-hours?

Would you use the equations for a pulse transformer to design a ignition transformer?

I'm trying to understand how an CDI **ignition coil** is designed. Something that looks like it can handle 120watts at best, handling 60kW in 1ms.

- If something is designed to run at 120watts continuously is it just inherent it will handle running at 60kW for 1ms?
- What is the formula to figure that out?
- What is the nomenclature to research it properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$ E = P \times t $$
Energy is power by time.

If your ignition coil outputs the same energy regardless of the duration then yes, the average power must reduce if you extend the time.

The energy in your example is given by \$ E = Pt = 60k \times 1m = 60 \ \text J \$.

> What is the formula to convert watts-miliseconds to watts-seconds or watts-hours?

\$ 1 \ \text {Wh} = 60 \times 60 \ \text {Ws} = 3600 \ \text {Ws} = 3.6 \ \text {kWs} \$.

Converting to watt-milliseconds is likely to cause confusion as the abbreviation will be kmWs or similar.

Comment: 1000 watt-milliseconds just becomes 1kWms ... or add a dot in between 1kW • ms to make it more clear

Comment: I like your "regardless of the duration" ... it makes me wonder what the target of the question is. An ignition with a duration of 10 seconds.. i would call it a heater

Comment: Sorry. cut me off. I'm trying to understand how an CDI **ignition coil** is designed. Something that looks like it can handle 120watts at best, handling 60kW in 1ms.
If something is designed to run at 120watts continously is it just inherent it will handle running at 60kW for 1ms?
What is the formula to figure that out? What is the nomenclature to research it properly?

Comment: @bteddy1 To understand the power handling, you need to understand both the heating effect (where averaging might be safe) and the transient conditions. Eventually, your 1ms pulse will cause voltage breakdown, or allow something to melt.

Answer (score 0):

Energy can be stored, as in a flywheel (for a magneto ignition), a coil (for
a 'conventional' automobile ignition), or a capacitor (for capacitor discharge ignition).

If you have a CDI ignition, the energy storage is the capacitor.   There is
no reason to expect a burst of energy to relate to  stored energy in the
coil.

Most electronics is intended for steady-state power, at or near continuous
output for lighting, motors, heaters.    An ignition spark is NOT
continuous, it's a short burst with a long pause, so the 'coil' can
work at power levels that would burn it up in continuous operation, as long
as it can rest between short spark events.

To keep short bursts from destabilizing the battery-power systems of an auto,
energy must be taken slowly into storage, then the burst of energy comes
from that storage (not directly from the battery and battery wiring).

Energy is power times time; spark energy of 60 W-s (that's watt-seconds)
can be 60 kW for 1 ms, on output, and can be 40W for 1.5 s on input to
the storage element.   The 'm' prefix means one-thousandth, the 'k' means
one thousand, so the product of power (watts) and time (seconds) is
the energy (and it matches, as it must when energy is conserved).   The
heat of the spark is going to be nearly all of that energy, maybe 50 W-s
of energy becomes the hot spark.